# Prevent scroll outside of the ul li dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

I have a code like below

https://plnkr.co/edit/LG8cOx?p=preview

I am trying to make a dropdown of ul li, in which i can scroll and select the element by enter. Now if page height is more like in example i have given, the scrolls on the ul li scrolls the page also. How do i prevent this?

```
.newMarginBottom {
  min-height: 1100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZHOIDP?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui - Works perfect!! Whats the fix. Could not find the change.

Comment: I return `false` from handler `(keydown)="!!eventHandler($event)"` notice `!!`. You can also use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @yurzui - When i fix the height of ul element and add scroll bar. Key board event does not scroll it. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `max-height` property

```
.newMarginBottom {
  max-height: 1100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Update 1:

arrow keys issue can be resolved when you are using `max-height:auto`

**[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/g0vARsBgRNL2jbUPovAh?p=preview)**

Comment: :) . That was just a example to show my issue. My page is actually big size. So i put min height to replicate issue

Comment: so you dont want scrolling beyond the page width and at the initial also? use `max-height : auto`

Comment: May be you can remove newMarginBottom  css and see how the behavior of scroll in dropdown is. You will get to know.

Comment: what is your expectation i m confused. clearly elaborate

Comment: When i scroll inside the dropdown  using downarrow keys, when it reached the last li element it goes back to first element when there is no scroll bar in page. This is right. When there is a scroll bar on page, even when last li element is hit when i hit down arrow key page keeps moving down. Hope i am clear now. Issue with the dropdown scrolling